# error since update to Meteor Version 0.4

Tags: meteor

i have a template with list of input-elements. their value is the title-element of an document. The input-elemnts have an keyup-event, so that when i wrote in the input-element, the title will updated. when i focus the input-elemnt, the Session-variable selectedDoc is set with the id of the document. until then it works. In another template i have a following function:

```
Template.content.isSelected = function () {
 return !Session.equals("selectedDoc",null) ? 'small' : ''; 
}
```

When i used the function above in my code, the following error occurs.
when i focus an input-element and write something, after the first letter the the focus disappeared. the error occurs only by the first time, i focus an input-element.

what am I doing wrong? with Version 0.3.9 everything worked well.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

> What am I doing wrong?

You're not following Meteor or reading the changelog, so you haven't noticed the API changes.

If you read them, especially Spark, and adapt your code accordingly; your code will work on 0.4.

Comment: I have read the documentation and use the template preserve-function as follows:                                     Template.name.preserve({
  'input[id]': function (node) { return node.id; }
});